# using grep in bash shell

Tags: bash, grep

I am having trouble using the grep command in a while loop.  Here is my code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#FILE:  grep_track
#will read in a list of track IDs and grep the track data from the original track files
set=-x

track_list=Top95_HSI_forGrep.txt
track_path="/mnt/gpfs/backup/jpty_surge/kimberly/Launch_multiple_storms/input/$track_list"
outname=$track_list

#echo track_list $track_list
#echo track_path $track_path
#echo outname $outname

IFS=$","
while read trackid fileid 
do
   file="input/track_param_$fileid"
   outfile="output/$outname"
   echo fileid $fileid
   echo trackid $trackid
   echo file $file
   echo outfile $outfile
   grep $trackid $file > $outfile 
done < $track_path
```

Everything appears to be reading in correctly (according to my echo responses), however I am getting the following error:

```
: No such file or directory1.txt
```

Could anyone help me figure out what is going on?  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a line in `/mnt/gpfs/backup/jpty_surge/kimberly/Launch_multiple_storms/input/Top95_HSI_forGrep.txt` contains two or more commas.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  When I enter this all on the command line it works fine.

Comment: OK. Change `set=-x` to `set -x` to enable debugging.

Comment: oK, it is telling me that file=$'input/track_param_0001.txt,\r'

Comment: Definitely just something wrong with the formatting of my input file.  Thanks for your help in guiding me to this!

Comment: It is a carriage return problem.  Do you have any idea how to remove the \r?  Thanks!  I tried some sed commands that do not work.

Comment: See my answer for `tr` usage.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24087/discussion-between-johnsyweb-and-kimmyjo221)

Comment: The primary problem is likely that your data file came from a Windows machine but the CRLF line endings were not changed to NL line endings on Unix.  There are multiple ways to do that conversion, ranging from using ASCII (instead of BIN) mode in FTP, to `dos2unix` or `dtou` programs, to `vim` (`:set filemode=unix`) to `tr`.

Comment: Thanks.  THis is definitely the problem.  The file was built using excel on a Windows machine.  I will research some of these options.  Thanks.

Comment: I used dos2unix and it resolved the issue!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quote your arguments to `grep`:

```
grep "${trackid}" "${file}" >> "${outfile}"
```

This way if either `$trackid` or `$file` contains whitespace, it will be treated as one argument to `grep` rather than multiple arguments. Note that [`>>` *appends*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Appending-Redirected-Output) to the file "`${outfile}`" (rather than [`>`, which would *truncate*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output)).

---

To remove the errant `\r`s from your input file, use [**tr(1)**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/tr/):

```
tr -d '\r' < "${track_path}" | while read trackid fileid 
# [...]
done
```

I also recommend some sanity checking, such as:

```
if [[ -f "${file}" ]] ; then
    grep "${trackid}" "${file}" > "${outfile}"
else
    echo "Could not find file [${file}]. Skipping."
fi
```

So your finished script *may* look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

track_list=Top95_HSI_forGrep.txt
track_path="${1-/mnt/gpfs/backup/jpty_surge/kimberly/Launch_multiple_storms/input}/${track_list}"
outname="${track_list}"
output_directory="output"
outfile="${output_directory}/${outname}"

if [[ ! -f "${track_path}" ]]; then
    echo "Could not find track_path input [${track_path}]. Exiting"
    exit
fi

if [[ ! -d "${output_directory}" ]] ; then
    echo "Creating output directory [${output_directory}]..."
    mkdir -p "${output_directory}"
fi

IFS=$","
tr -d '\r' < "${track_path}" | while read trackid fileid
do
    file="input/track_param_${fileid}"
    if [[ -f "${file}" ]]; then
        grep "${trackid}" "${file}" >> "${outfile}"
    else
        echo "Could not find file [${file}]. Skipping."
    fi
done
```

Comment: I tried this, and it says:  `line 23: {output/Top95_HSI_forGrep.txt}: no such file or directory`

Comment: Exists and is writable.  Can you think of anything else that might be going wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: grep "${trackid}" "${fileid}" >> "${outname}"

Comment: actually coded this way the error is back to what I originally quoted:  : No such file or directory1.txt

Comment: it is having trouble finding the input file $fileid, which is track_param_0001.txt

Comment: unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: Can you define "did not work"? Did it not remove the `\r`s?

Comment: @kimmyjo221: I missed a `<`. Fixed.